# Laravel AJAX update not working for updating values in DB

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel

Function in controller

```
public function updateajax(Request $request)
{
    $item= Model::where('unq_identifier', $request->unq_identifier)->first();
    $item->status= $request->status;
    $item->save();
    return response()->json($item);
}
```

Ajax Function

```
$.ajax({  
                url:'/main-tables/update-ajax/' + id,  
                method:'PUT',  
                data:{
                    _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                    status: value,
                    unq_identifier: unq_identifier,
                    user_id : {{ Auth::user()->id }}
                    },  
                success:function(data){  
                    // if(data == "updated")
                    console.log(data);
                }  
            });
```

when i'm printing the data in the success function the object in here has the updated value but the item doesn't get updated in the DB.

Comment: Are you still stucked ?

Answer (score 0):

You should pack every DB interaction query inro try-catch block. It is best practice to see if the DB operation is successful or not

```
public function updateajax(Request $request)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $item= Model::where('unq_identifier', $request->unq_identifier)->first();
        $item->status= $request->status;
        $item->save();
        DB::commit();
        return response()->json($item);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        return response()->json($e->getMessage(), 400);
    }
}
```

Now see if your query got executed successfully or not by checking the api response.